# Firebase Auth Token Persistence Security Risks

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

**Current Setup**

I'm using cloud functions and the admin sdk for my backend. The front-end is a combination of React, Firebase Auth (web sdk), and redux firebase for authentication. Currently, I force a token refresh for each request for specific components of my react app and save the token to local storage.

**Reasoning**

Initially, I thought I could simply listen for the auth state to change in my front-end's index.js and then refresh the token accordingly i.e. `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` A few processes on my app can take quite a while (i.e. uploading content) and I've noticed the change of auth state doesn't get triggered anytime outside of the initial login or a logout.

For example, the user begins to upload content 1 minute before the token is set to expire. The final API requests following the uploading then fail because they finish after the token has expired. The token doesn't get updated and requests fail to my backend as 403 unauthorized. The solution was to use `currentUser.getIdToken(true)` upon the first load of each of these components. Therefore ensuring a new token is always available.

**Problem**

Are there security risks to this approach? If yes, how can I mitigate them or is there a better approach to persist the token? I'm nervous about giving users the ability to indefinitely refresh their tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a better approach to persist the token?

You're supposed to use [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) to listen to changes in the user's ID token as it changes over time.  It works like `onAuthStateChanged`, except you get fed ID tokens.  It's updated automatically as needed by the client SDK.  You can store the latest token for use in your calls without having to fetch one with an API call each time.

> Are there security risks to this approach?

Not really.  Refreshing an ID token is necessary, and the Auth SDK does it automatically internally anyway.

Comment: That did the trick, Doug. As always, I appreciate your help!